# Join multiple tables in SQL

Tags: join

I hope someone could help me today with my sql query. I don't do much sql but suddenly need to run one today. I have 4 tables that I need to combine into one with table 1 (Queue Table) as the base. I need to know which support group is doing what queue.
Below is an example of an end result that I am trying to find out. Please let me know how to do this in SQL, i know join will do the trick but I am not so familiar yet in SQL other than the regular select  query.
I have a requirement to know the support group handling each queue.

Ideally, I am looking for this result.
Queue ID    Queue Name  SupportGroupID  Support Group Name
1230    customer service    12  Russel
1231    tech support    13  Martin
1232    sales support   14  Arthur
1233    vendor support  15  Kennedy

May I also know who is the team member per each Support Group, if only possible?

Please refer to below table for the source or also in the attached.

Would you also tell me if you need anything else from me.

Thanks very much in advanced for all the help.

Queue Table 1
Queue_ID    Queue_Name
1230    customer service
1231    tech support
1232    sales support
1233    vendor support

Queue+Support Group Table 2 
Queue_ID    SupportGroupID
1230    12
1231    13
1232    14
1233    15

Support Group Table 3
Support_Group_ID    Support_GroupName
12  Russel
13  Martin
14  Arthur
15  Kennedy

Support Group Member Table 4
Support_GroupID Member_Name
12  Rina
12  Osmon
12  Desiree
13  Maria
13  Todorov
14  Kyle
14  Andrew
14  Mark
15  Demi
15  Cher
15  Christine

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiTOI.jpg)
[IdealEndResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydn5l.jpg)

Comment: Any attempts you've made? Have you tried joining 2 tables first? Then join table A & B, C & D, and join the AB & CD combinations?

Comment: hi there @Evert, So I did multiple joins and that worked. I posted my exact sql query in my last message here. Let me know what you think, too. That could be simplify I know. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You would be looking to use an SQL JOIN. The way this works is you need a column in one table to have a value that references a row in another table. This is known as a foreign key. I'm not going to show you how to solve your problem because it would take too much time for me to work out but below is a simple example with customers and addresses that if you can understand you will find your problem really simple. (I suggest you look into Primary Keys and Foreign Keys)

Suppose I have 2 tables, tbl_customers and tbl_addresses. They look like this:

```
tbl_customers: PK_CUSTOMER_ID | FK_ADDRESS_ID | First_Name | Last_Name
                     0                0           person1     lname1
                     1                1           person2     lname2
                     2                0           person3     lname1

tbl_addresses: PK_ADDRESS_ID | House_Number | Road_Name | Post_Code
                     0              123        fake rd     AB1 2CD
                     1              456        new ln      ZY9 8XW
```

So after brefiely reading that you can see that person1 and person3 live at the same address and share a last name, while person2 lives on their own (according to out database) and has a separate last name. Suppose we want to get all of a persons information and their address. This is where something like an INNER JOIN statement can be used. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_customers INNER JOIN tbl_addresses ON FK_ADDRESS_ID = PK_ADDRESS_ID WHERE First_Name = 'person1'
```

This would return a table looking like:

```
PK_CUSTOMER_ID | FK_ADDRESS_ID | First_Name | Last_Name | PK_ADDRESS_ID | House_Number | Road_Name | Post_Code
      0               0           person1      lname1           0             123         fake rd     AB1 2CD
```

Hope this helps, if you need help you are best searching on Google for SQL JOINs. Good Luck :)

-- James

Edit - INNER JOIN may or may not be the best JOIN for your situation, I normally use it because its fairly flexible for all of my needs and I haven't yet come across a scenario where it wasn't useful.

Second Edit - Just realised this may not answer your question on joining more than 2 tables. This is just as easy, lets say I have another table called tbl_orders and I wanted to select all of the information from all three tables, the statement would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_customers INNER JOIN tbl_addresses ON FK_ADDRESS_ID = PK_ADDRESS_ID INNER JOIN tbl_orders ON FK_PERSON_ID = PK_PERSON_ID WHERE First_Name = 'person1'
```

Something along those lines. You can have as many JOINs as you need.

Comment: Thanks so much but I dont know what kind of join I did. It you notice in my last post as my solution, I use multiple joins but not right, left or inner. just a simple JOIN. i will research more as to what kind of join that falls into :) Thanks for your long comment anyway. It gave a information as well on the other side of Join.

Answer (score 0):

So I wanted to share with you that I found a video in youtube courtesy of Mr Jamie King and I was able to solve the problem by using his query as a pattern. But I see a lot of responses right away (which is making me so glad today). I will find time to respond to each of you as I am really grateful that you all took time to look into my query.
here is the query I created which is also JOIN. It works fine and dandy. It might be longer and coding is more conventional than usual.

```
SELECT [imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Call_Type].[CallTypeID],
        [imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Call_Type].[EnterpriseName],
        [imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Call_Type_SG_Interval].SkillGroupSkillTargetID,
        [imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Skill_Group].[EnterpriseName],
        [imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Skill_Group_Member].[SkillGroupSkillTargetID],
        [imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Agent].[SkillTargetID],
        [imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Agent].[EnterpriseName]
  FROM [imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Call_Type] join [imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Call_Type_SG_Interval] on [imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Call_Type].CallTypeID=[imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Call_Type_SG_Interval].CallTypeID
  join Skill_Group
  on [imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Call_Type_SG_Interval].SkillGroupSkillTargetID=[imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Skill_Group].[SkillTargetID]
  join Skill_Group_Member
  on [imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Skill_Group].[SkillTargetID]=[imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Skill_Group_Member].[SkillGroupSkillTargetID]
  join Agent
  on [imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Skill_Group_Member].[AgentSkillTargetID]=[imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Agent].[SkillTargetID]
  order by [imucc_awdb].[dbo].[Call_Type].[EnterpriseName]
```

Answer (score -1):

While you say you are not familiar with SQL joins, it is kind of requirement to learn if you want to use SQL.  A left join is what you are seeking.  So you are joining table1 with table2 on queue_id on both tables.  In the same query you are joining table2 with table3 on the same foreign key.  You can see the pattern.  See this page: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: Thanks @user594643. I will look into that link you sent because I agree with you that it is now a requirement to learn sql... at least in this job that I have.